# Faster drop() in R

Tags: arrays, r

drop() in R is already pretty fast (since it is an internal function) for large arrays.

Is there anything faster for very-large arrays (e.g., genomics)?

The 'abind' package has 'adrop()', but it is written in pure R and is orders of magnitude slower.

Here are some benchmarks:

```
library(bench)

x <- array(1:(10000 * 1000), dim = c(10000, 1000, 1))
bench::mark(drop(x), adrop(x, drop = 3))

Unit: nanoseconds
    expr             min    lq     mean  median      uq    max neval
           drop(x)   570   661   905.56   986.5  1069.5   3631   100
adrop(x, drop = 3) 20962 21370 24563.73 21603.5 21880.5 297273   100
```